# Ajax Error “SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character”

Tags: json, jquery

I am using jquery with ajax. I can pass data successfully, but I am getting error of "**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character**"

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    method:'post',
    dataType:'json',
    url: "storeEventData.php",
    data: $('#recuringForm').serialize(),
    onSuccess: function(response){
         alert("hello");
    },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
           console.log(errorThrown);
        }

});
```

Here is storeEventData.php code:

```
<?php 

ob_start();

// Start the session
session_start();

$_SESSION = $_POST;

echo '<pre>'; print_r($_SESSION); exit;
?>
```

let me know where I am going wrong?

Thank you

Comment: paste code from storeEventData.php

Comment: @hex4, I have add storeEventData.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) I don't think you actually can do assign the $_POST to the $_SESSION variable.  You need to do something like `$_SESSION['post'] = $_POST`

2) You have `datatype: 'json'` hence you need to echo from the php script using `json_encode`

Comment: I have try as per your suggestion. Syntax error resolved, But I am not getting success event.

Comment: it's not `onSuccess`, it's just `success`

Answer (score 0):

Just replace the bit of code as follows

Replace:

```
onSuccess: function(response){
     alert("hello");
}
```

To:

```
success: function(response){
     alert("hello");
}
```